# Positioning SWT Text free in Window/Shell

Tags: java, position, swt

How is it possible to position text in an [SWT Shell](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html)?

My problem is that I don't know which Layout to use. I've tried Row and Fill-Layout, but this won't work if I do it like `text.setLocation(x,y)`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use a layout? What kind of GUI are you designing?

Comment: I want to design an GUI which can be used to create as first an Brainstorming and then out of it a Mind Map. So I need to position the text somewhere in the window.

Comment: If you're basically trying to create a graph structure (which is what a mind map is), you should have a look at [Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/) and [draw2d](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

If you use no Layout, put the elements you want in a SWT Group, you can position it free inside this group.

```
Group group = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
Text text = new Text(group, SWT.BORDER);
group.setSize(parent.getSize());
text.setLocation(parent.getSize().x/2, parent.getSize().y/2);
```

Will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth taking a look at FormLayout. Would go something like:

```
Group group = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
group.setLayout(new FormLayout());

Text text = new Text(group, SWT.BORDER);
text.setText("Text1");

FormData fd = new FormData();
fd.top = new FormAttachment(50,0);
fd.left = new FormAttachment(50,0);

text.setLayoutData(fd);
```

The [FormAttachment](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/FormAttachment.html) class lets you specify both a percentage of the container width (50% in this case), and also a fixed offset(0).